# program that will display an o on the board after randomly chosen

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Sorry about the code before. This is code for the computer. If the user selects the coordinate N1 then it randomly selects another coordinate that is can block that position. This is part of a tic tac toe game that I am trying to make in java. I am having trouble      getting an x to print on the coordinate. If you can help me I would greatly appreciate it.
just simple ai.

```
here is the code:

import java.util.*;
public class compbrain{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
 char x = 'X';
 char [][] ar = new char [3][3];
 System.out.println("Player X: Enter the coordinate where you want an X placed. Example    1 0");
 int choice1 = input.nextInt();
 int choice2 = input.nextInt();
 char N = ar[choice1][choice2] = x;
  char N1 = ar[0][0];
  char N2 = ar[0][1];
  char N3 = ar[0][2];
  char N4 = ar[1][0];
  char N5 = ar[1][1];
  char N6 = ar[1][2];
  char N7 = ar[2][0];
  char N8 = ar[2][1];
  char N9 = ar[2][2];
 int r = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
 char [] arrayN1 = {N4,N7,N2,N3,N5,N9};


 if(N == N1){arrayN1[r] = x;}

 System.out.println("      0     1      2     ");
    System.out.println("   --------------------");
    System.out.println("0  |  "+N1+"  |   "+N4+"  |  "+N7+"  |");
    System.out.println("   --------------------");
    System.out.println("1  |  "+N2+"  |   "+N5+"  |  "+N8+"  |");
    System.out.println("   --------------------");
    System.out.println("2  |  "+N3+"  |   "+N6+"  |  "+N9+"  |");
    System.out.println("   --------------------");
}
}
```

Comment: What coordinate? What do you do with arrayN1 and r??

Comment: arrayN1 contains the 2d arrays N4,N7,N2,N3,N5,N9. r randomly generates a number. r picks the index of arrayN1. I want arrayN1 to display an o on the board on whatever coordinate the index of arrayN1 is.

Comment: What 'trouble'?  Pretend we cannot read your mind and are not sitting in front of your computer.

Comment: the coordinate is randomly generated by arrayN1[r]. the problem is that it is not printing on the generated coordinate. N1 through N9 are 2d arrays that contain the coordinates

Comment: N1 to N9 are single chars, no arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out now what your problem is.

Here's a solution:

```
// Setting a random field to 'o'
Random r = new Random();
int a = r.nextInt(3);
int b = r.nextInt(3);

ar[a][b] = o;

// Printing the fields
System.out.println("      0     1      2     ");
System.out.println("   --------------------");
System.out.println("0  |  " + ar[0][0] + "  |  " + ar[1][0] + "  |  " + ar[2][0] + "  |");
// and so on
```

arrayN1 never contained any array, just the copy of the copy of the values at ar[1][0] and the others.

By changing the values in arrayN1 you never changed some of your Nx chars or the values in ar[][]